# Resend an apple event to other process from 'main'

Tags: objective-c, events

Application not running. A plugin send file(s) to application to open its. Application perform 'application:openFiles:' method. In 'main.m' of this application running another process via '[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:arguments:]'. Can anyone tell me, how to perform 'application:openFiles:' in second process with same parameters, because second process don't known about sended files to open. 
Maybe there another way to make this thing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `-[NSWorkspace openFile:withApplication:]`?

Comment: No, I must do all before calling 'NSApplicationMain'.

Comment: Program has been writed with 'current logic' and I can't change that.
I must run another instance of application in 'main.m', before 'NSApplicationMain', and it another instance must open those files.

Thank you, Jonathan.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you cannot modify the code in your application, you're not going to be able to do anything.

Comment: Sorry, I can modify code, but will be better, if existing code stay as is. What do you suggest to do?